# Как объявить generic функцию, если это результат другого выражения?

Tags: typescript, lodash, typescript-типы

Допустим, имеется некая generic функция:

```
type MyMap {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}
const lookupProperty = <K extends keyof MyMap>(key: K, map: MyMap)
  : MyMap[K] => map[key]
```

Проблемы появляются, когда я пытюсь объявить generic функцию, которая является некого выражения, например, в моем случае это каррированная версия оригинальной:

```
function curry<T1, T2, ..., TN, R>(fn) {...}

const curriedLookup = curry(lookupProperty)
```

где `fn` - каррируемая функция, `T1, ... TN`  - типы ее аргументов,  `R` - тип возвращаемого значения

Для сохранения типизации, мне необходимо что-то типа

```
const curriedLookup = <K extends keyof MyMap>curry<K, MyMap>(lookupProperty)
```

но это не валидный tipescript синтаксис, как и если попробовать сделать 
generic левую часть выражения (`curriedLookup`)

Comment: `@types/lodash`

Comment: я не понял с какой именно функцией проблема? lookupProperty, curry или curriedLookup?

Comment: и непонятно что именно ты ожидаешь получить в итоге, и что получаешь на данный момент - ошибку или неверное поведение